# confused with basic python code

Tags: python, while-loop

I do not understand this code. I am thinking that while iterLeft is not equal to 0 it adds ans to x.
answer is 0 x is 3 which equals 3.
Iterleft - 1 = 2

`print str(x)` should print 2 because x is 2, and then 2 again, and then ans which is 3

what is wrong with my explanation

```
x = 3
ans = 0
itersLeft = x
while (itersLeft != 0):
     ans = ans + x
     itersLeft = itersLeft - 1
print str(x) + '*' + str(x) + ' = ' + str(ans)
```

Comment: You might want to fix your indentation to match your real code.

Comment: the code is displayed exactly how i found it, it a Python book from two MIT lecturers.

Comment: This is pretty simple code; you should read up on loops and variables if you don't understand it. A great website to start to learn Python: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm

Comment: It prints "3 * 3 = 9". It is difficult to argue with that.

Comment: [Learn Code the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) by Z Shaw is pretty good too.

Comment: As a warning, don't insult users in your questions. NPE has absolutely nothing to do with your account (which isn't suspended, by the way).

Answer (score 5):

> what is wrong with my explanation

`x` is set to `3` and then never changed. I don't see how you can expect `print str(x)` to print `2`.

> it adds `ans` to `x`

No, it's the other way around: `ans = ans + x`  adds `x` to `ans`.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is `3` always because you not change it under while loop.

you have to give `indentation after while loop`

Comment: That's just a text formatting error when posting it here, not the real issue